# Doctrine 2: Separate chain calls in QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

What is the approach to separate the querybuilder if I have some condition that I want to check.

What I want to get is something like this:

```
 public function getProfilePhotoByUserId($userId, $checkApproved = false)
 {
        $profile = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.user = :userId')

            ->andWhere('p.profile = 1')

            ->setParameter('userId', $userId);

        if($checkApproved) $profile->andWhere('p.approved = 1');

        $profile->getQuery();

        return $profile->getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
 }
```

However this shows error on getOneOrNullResult:

"Method not found in querybuilder"

Answer (score 0):

`getQuery()` return a Doctrine\ORM\Query object.

```
$query = $profile->getQuery();

return query->getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

or

```
return $profile->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```